# Can we deploy our existing applications that are in EJB 2.0 and Struts 1.x to WebLogic 12.1.2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, struts, struts-1

We have an Old Application which is based on EJB 2.0 and Struts 1.X and running on Weblogic 8.X Server. Can we deploy this application in Weblogic 12.1.2?

Currently we are upgrading of WebLogic 8.x to WebLogic 11.1.2 as our existing applications are in EJB 2.0 and Struts 1.x.

Can we deploy this applications to New Version WebLogic 12.1.2 with out changing any EJB Version and Struts Version? 
No Any Change in the Versions at application layer.

Answer (score 0):

It has support for old applications. See [Table 1 Java Standards Support](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/toc.htm#NOTES128).

About Struts 1.x, if you can use 1.3 the servlet 2.3 is available.

> The Struts 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 versions require only version 2.2 or
>   later of the Servlet Specification to be implemented by your servlet
>   container, so those versions do not use Filters. Beginning with the
>   1.3 version, a container that supports version 2.3 or later of the Servlet Specification is required.